Flutter listview live filter/search
I have this code in Flutter. Why doesn't listview.builder live re-render with results?
I want to live filter a listview to improve the search. I tried many YT tutorials and online tutorials, but no one got me where i need.
Please help me with this struggle.
I tried this: https://karthikponnam.medium.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685 but no result.
class _UnitsPage extends State<UnitsPage> {
  late Future<List<UnitModel>> units;
  late Future<List<Speciality>> specialities;
  Speciality? _selectedSpeciality;
  late List<Speciality> items;
  late List<Speciality> originalSpecialities;

  final TextEditingController _searchSpeciality = TextEditingController();

  late Future<Position> position;

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    units = getUnits();
    specialities = getSpecialities();
  }

  @override
  void dispose()
  {
    super.dispose();
    _searchSpeciality.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _refreshUnits() async
  {
    if(_selectedSpeciality != null)
    {
      setState(() {
        units = getUnits(specialityId: _selectedSpeciality!.id);
      });
    }
    else{
      setState(() {
        units = getUnits(specialityId: 0);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String selectedSpeciality = 'Selecteaza specialitatea';

    if(_selectedSpeciality != null) {
      selectedSpeciality = _selectedSpeciality!.name;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const Menu(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light, //<-- For Android SEE HERE (dark icons)
          statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, //<-- For iOS SEE HERE (dark icons)
        ),
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xff058efc),
                    Color(0xff74c0fc)
                  ]
              )
          ),
        ),
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Transform.translate(
            offset: const Offset(-20.0, 0.0),
            child: const Text('Unități medicale', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
            ),
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
                FutureBuilder<List<Speciality>>(
                future: specialities,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    items  = snapshot.data!;
                    originalSpecialities = snapshot.data!;
                    return BootstrapRow(
                      children: [
                        BootstrapCol(
                            child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(selectedSpeciality),
                              onPressed: (){
                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                  isScrollControlled: true,
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context){
                                      return FractionallySizedBox(
                                        heightFactor: 0.8,
                                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            child: BootstrapRow(
                                              children: [
                                                BootstrapCol(
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 16),
                                                      child: TextField(
                                                        controller: _searchSpeciality,
                                                        onChanged: (search) {
                                                          searchSpeciality(search);
                                                        },
                                                      )
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                                BootstrapCol(
                                                    child: SizedBox(
                                                      height: 700,
                                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                                        itemCount: items.length,
                                                          itemBuilder: (context , index){
                                                            return ListTile(
                                                              tileColor: (_selectedSpeciality != null && _selectedSpeciality!.id == items[index].id) ? const Color(0xff058efc) : null,
                                                              textColor: (_selectedSpeciality != null && _selectedSpeciality!.id == items[index].id) ? Colors.white : null,
                                                              onTap: (){
                                                                setState(() {
                                                                  _selectedSpeciality = items[index];
                                                                });
                                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                                              },
                                                              title: Text(items[index].name),
                                                            );
                                                          }
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                      );
                                    }
                                );
                              },
                            )
                        ),
                        BootstrapCol(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                _refreshUnits();
                              },
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              ),
                              child: const Text("Caută")
                            )
                        )
                      ]
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text('No data available');
                  }
                },
              ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<UnitModel>>(
                    future: units,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      switch(snapshot.connectionState)
                      {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                          {
                            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue));
                          }
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          {
                            return BootstrapRow(
                              children: [
                                for(UnitModel unit in snapshot.data!)
                                  BootstrapCol(
                                      xs: 6,
                                      child: UnitWidget(unit: unit)
                                  )
                              ],
                            );
                          }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ],
      ))
    );
  }

  void searchSpeciality(String search)
  {
    setState(() {
      items = originalSpecialities
          .where((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }
}```


Whenever you reset the state the future builders are called again. Hence you have to wait for the elements to re render.

I also tried this tutorial, but still no success:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHdg2kfKmjI&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com

Use a boolean set to true to indicate loading and execute the futures in init state and once the future is complete set state the boolean to false in turn rendering your list and when you update the list the futures will not be called again.

if you have multiple async operations called one by one then instead of FutureBuilder use StreamBuilder
